# How to solve cy.type() failed because it targeted a disabled element without adding {force: true}

Tags: angular, angular-material, cypress

**Information about application:**

- Application: Angular
- Form field: input which is wrapped in a mat-form-filed
- Cypress version: 10.6.0

**Angular Template**

```
<mat-form-field
  appearance="fill"
  color="accent"
  class="workbook-input"
  [id]="cell.address"
  [class.error]="!inputValidLength()">
  <input
    [disabled]="isDisabled"
    [readonly]="readonly"
    class="workbook-cell"
    appFontStyle
    [appIsItalic]="cell.isItalic"
    [appIsBold]="cell.isBold"
    [appAlignment]="cell.alignment"
    matInput
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    (focusout)="onInputChange()"
    (keydown.enter)="onInputChange()"
    [placeholder]="getPlaceholderValue()"
    [appCellFocus]="cell.address"
    data-cy="input-content" />
</mat-form-field>
```

**Cypress Test Case**

```
  it("E2E_Input_001", () => {
    cy.getRowByTestTitle()
      .find('[data-cy="input-content"]')
      .should("be.enabled")
      .focus()
      .type("Test Input 123{enter}");
    cy.wait("@INPUT_REQUEST");
    cy.getRowByTestTitle()
      .find('[data-cy="info-content"]')
      .should("have.text", " Test Input 123 ");
  });
```

**Problem:**
When cypress is trying to type in the input the will fail because of the following error:
[image]

However I assert its disability before typing:
[image]

**I already know that I can avoid this error by adding {force: true} but It sounds like a HACK to me I need to know about the root cause. Thanks**

Comment: What prevents you from enabling the input? It's disabled because `isDisabled` is truthy.

Comment: `isDisabled` is `true`. As I said `.should("be.enabled")` is asserted successfully.

Comment: Yes, it was enabled at the time of the assertion, then you used .focus() on the same element. That may have changed the isDisabled value.

Comment: I tested even without the disabled attribute. As I investigate, event listeners from directives can cause this. but I don't know how and why?!

Comment: You are correct, the element has no `disabled` attribute - also Angular thinks the same thing (`ng-reflect-is-disabled="false"`). Need to look at why Cypress thinks so, may be a bug.